# Escape curly braces progress abl

Tags: progress-4gl

How do i escape curly braces  progress abl from a display statement ??

Our friend google didn't find any info

```
DISPLAY "{"httCust":[]}"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use tilde ~ to escape the  curly braces & double quates

```
DISPLAY "~{~"httCust~":[]~}"
```

Comment: In reality you need to escape the " as well (as you've done) but only the starting curly brace. Curly braces is the syntax for preprocessors - that's why you need them escaped... The second tilde doesn't hurt though. If you use single quotes on the outside you don't need to escape the quotes. `DISPLAY '~{"httCust":[]}'`

Comment: @Jensd documentation for progress is small to none, and the learning curve as steep as a ravine :)

Comment: You just dont know where to look! Check out documentation.progress.com! Check the openedge-tag information - lots of links there. Good luck!